# Excel vlookup right 5 character from array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to search the right 5 characters of array $A:$B for the value in column C and return a concatenated value of column A, "." and column B.

```
00010025     0     10025     00010025.0
00010026     0     10026     00010026.0
00010027     0     10027     00010027.0
00010029     0     10028     NoMatch
00010055     1     10054     NoMatch
00010101     1     10101     00010101.1
00010102     1     10102     00010102.1
```

This works if the value in ColumnC has the leading zeros.  However, the "raw" data is only 5 characters.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($D12,$A:$B,2,FALSE)),0,CONCATENATE($D12,".",VLOOKUP($D12,$A:$B,2,FALSE)))
```

Comment: I don't understand what D12 has to do with it - there are only seven rows of data.

Comment: Sorry, I grabbed that from a different "testing" cell. D had the value with 8 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are really good if the values in A and C are numbers with leading zeros, but what if they are text values where the last five characters just happen to match (like order numbers or something).  Assuming that the values in C and the ones in A are different but just happen to match the last 5 characters try this:

If you enter this into D1 as an array formula (Control-Shift-Enter) it will return an array of the row numbers in A that match the nalue in C or 0 for rows that didn't match:

```
=IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT(A:A,5),ROW(A:A),0)
```

So that means this will return the last row in A that matches the value in C or 0 if nothing matched:

```
=MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT(A:A,5),ROW(A:A),0))
```

So then we can do this to return the value from A if it matches the value in C:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT(A:A,5),ROW(A:A),0)))
```

And we can do this to return the concate of A and B for rows that match the value in C:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT(A:A,5),ROW(A:A),0)))&"."&INDEX(B:B,MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT(A:A,5),ROW(A:A),0)))
```

Then the only thing to worry about is to make it say NoMatch if 0 is returned:

```
=IF(MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT(A:A,5),ROW(A:A),0))=0,"NoMatch",INDEX(A:A,MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT(A:A,5),ROW(A:A),0)))&"."&INDEX(B:B,MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT(A:A,5),ROW(A:A),0))))
```

But wait.  There are a million rows in a spreadsheet so you don't want to use A:A and B:B unless you want it to take forever to calculate.  Instead use $A$1:$A$100 and $B$1:$B$100 (or something similar depending on how many rows you have):

```
=IF(MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT($A$1:$A$100,5),ROW($A$1:$A$100),0))=0,"No Match",INDEX($A$1:$A$100,MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT($A$1:$A$100,5),ROW($A$1:$A$100),0)))&"."&INDEX($B$1:$B$100,MAX(IF(RIGHT(C1,5)=RIGHT($A$1:$A$100,5),ROW($A$1:$A$100),0))))
```

So enter that in D1 as an array formula by pressing Control-Shift-Enter you can copy it down to every row that has a value in C.  It will calculate much faster if you don't use A:A and B:B and produces this:

```
XYZ$WERTY    1      98712345    987612345.7
 76523456    2      87623456    76523456.2
987612345    3       6534567    65434567.4
 65434567    4      65445678    654345678.5
654345678    5     654356789    No Match
 21678901    6      43267890    No Match
987612345    7    ABC-QWERTY    XYZ$WERTY.1
```

Comment: This works perfect!  Thank you very much for the detailed step by step explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference between column A and C is the leading 0, your formula could be `=C2&vlookup(text(C2,"00000000"),A:B,2,0)`

Or just run Text To Columns on column A.

Answer (score 0):

First, swap out the `If(ISERROR(...` for the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5). It greatly reduces the code.

When you concatenate numbers, you end up with a string that looks like a number. This is generally not a preferred situation.

[image]

The formula that produces a string that looks like a number in D2 is,

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT("000000" & VLOOKUP(VALUE(C2),A:B, 1, FALSE), 8)&CHAR(46)& VLOOKUP(VALUE(C2),A:B, 2, FALSE), "No Match")
```

The formula that produces an actual number (but uses a custom number formatting mask of *00000000.0* to show leading zeroes in E2 is,

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(VLOOKUP(VALUE(C2),A:B, 1, FALSE)&CHAR(46)& VLOOKUP(VALUE(C2),A:B, 2, FALSE)), "No Match")
```

Note that by default, the results in column D are left aligned. This indicates text. The actual numbers in column E are right aligned.

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: I am not able to make this formula work.  I guess because in your example Column C has the leading 0's.  In my data Column C does not have the leading 0's.  The data is all text, not numbers.

Comment: The raw values in column C do not contain leading zeroes. They are true numbers with a custom number format of *00000000*. You can visually tell that from their right alignment. But that is not salient; you have text that look like numbers without leading zeroes and text will not match a number even if they look identical. I'd suggest running a quick Text-toColumns, Fixed Width, Finish to convert them to actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&C1,$A:$B,1,FALSE)&"."&VLOOKUP("*"&C1,$A:$B,2,FALSE),"NoMatch")
```

This function uses `VLOOKUP` for the rightmost characters (not exactly five, if your number/string would be 8 digits, then that long).
If it finds a match, it returns the concatenated stuff, otherwise it will return your `NoMatch` string.

```
00010025    0   10025   00010025.0
00010026    0   10026   00010026.0
00010027    0   10027   00010027.0
00010029    0   10028   NoMatch
00010055    1   10054   NoMatch
00010101    1   10101   00010101.1
00010102    1   10102   00010102.1
              00010029  00010029.0
               0010102  00010102.1
```